# Why is innerHTML returning 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to catch the "value" inside this div, which is editable:

```
<div class="editable-div" contentEditable="true">Hey</div>
```

I figured I could do this simply via JavaScript:

```
var changedText = $('.editable-div').innerHtml
```

However, this variable will always return "undefined", which confuses me.

Can someone enlighten me on how to reach this "value"?

Comment: You are creating a jQuery object. It doesn't have `innerHTML` property. You should use the `html` method which reads the `innerHTML` property behind the scenes! `$('.editable-div').html()`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It is jQuery - you have to use:

```
$('.editable-div').html()
```

Comment: Ah duh, sometimes I'm not sure where Javascript ends and jQuery begins. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: if there's a `$` then it is likely jQuery

Comment: It comes with exp =-) jQuery - just a library, but powerful library ) dont forget about approve ans for improving SO

Comment: `innerHTML` is JavaScript; to correctly see the html, use jQuery's `.html()` function or `.text()` function.

Answer (score 3):

A jQuery wrapped object is actually not the raw DOM node, but essentially an array of raw DOM nodes that can be acted upon with jQuery specific methods, such as `.html()`. If you want to interact with the DOM node, you can retrieve it by either iterating through the list or getting the element of that list if you know which one it is:

```
$('div').each(function(index, element) {
  element.innerHTML // ...
}

$('div').get(0).innerHTML
$('div')[0].innerHTML
```

Note that while it is "kind of" like an array, in that you can get DOM nodes using the array syntax of `$('div')[0]`, you can't treat it like an array in Javascript. In other words, you **can't** do this:

```
$('div').forEach(function(element) {
  element.innerHTML
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`innerHtml` is used with javascript selector and you are using jQuery. so replace `innerHtml` with `.html()` or `.text()` function.

Use this:

```
var changedText = $('.editable-div').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

innerHtml is DOM. try $('.editable-div')[0].innerHtml