# Javascript cannot see element loaded with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I load div with PHP and then I want to get it from HTML using Javascript. Getting element by id alerts `undefined`.

```
 <?php echo "<div id='myDiv'>Hello</div>"; ?>
 <script>
     $( document ).ready(function() {
    alert( $("#myDiv").innerHTML)
});
</script>
```

How is that even possible?

Comment: Your question doesn't actually make sense: all PHP code is run before any JavaScript code, so there is no delay for the PHP to be "done loading". Presumably, there's actually a problem in the LoadOfficesTable function, but since you haven't shown it to us, we can't tell you what it is.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why is innerHTML returning 'undefined'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435612/why-is-innerhtml-returning-undefined) `document.getElementById()` or `document.querySelector()` return an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), which has a `innerHTML` property. `$("#myDiv")` returns a jQuery object, which doesn't have a `innerHTML` property, hence it is `undefined`. Use `$("#myDiv").html()`.